# Downside of using transaction dispose with entity framework integration testing

Tags: entity-framework, transactions, entity-framework-6.1

I am looking for a quick way to clean my tables data doing integration tests with EF.

Everyone seems to wrap a transaction around its test method and dispose the transaction after the test.

That way the data is never written to the table.

Things like new auto ids for inserts are still working but I ask myself wether this method is really reliable compared to .commit() the transaction.

Are there any downsides of using this approach which seem not to be a real integration test as the database is never touched...

Or asked in other words are there faulty scenarios which do not pop as exceptions using the transaction without commit() ?

UPDATE

```
public abstract class IntegrationTestsBase
    {
        protected TransactionScope TransactionScope;

        public abstract void TestSetup();
        protected void InitTestSetupOnTable(string tableName)
        {
            TransactionScope = new TransactionScope();

            using (var context = new TGBContext())
            {
                var cmdCommand = string.Format("DBCC CHECKIDENT ({0}, RESEED, 1)", tableName);
                context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(cmdCommand);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void TestCleanup()
        {
            TransactionScope.Dispose();
        }
    }

[TestClass]
public class MyTests : IntegrationTestsBase
{
        [TestInitialize]
        public override void TestSetup()
        {
            base.InitTestSetupOnTable("MyTableName");          
        }
}
```

Comment: The only real difference is that you don't test the concurrency. So when you will need (and you will need!) you will change the begin transaction/rollback approach. Also, restore a backup and drop a database are few line of codes at test beginning/end.

Comment: @bubi Restore a database is faster than context.datebase.Create() ?

Comment: If you can start tests with an empty database you can also use Create(). I don't know if it is faster probably depends on number of tables/fields/relationships/DBMS... Also, could be that some EF Provider does not support Create(). In my case I use Microsoft Access to test EF and the provider supports codefirst migrations but does not support Create()

Comment: Independently from the approach, you should avoid to test autonumbering fields. After some months for some reason they always stop work :)

Comment: When I reseed them they should always. I do not test the autoinc etc... that should work by design. I just rely on a certain Id = 1, because if there is something wrong I know the autoinc is broken/reseed does not work, the clean table/transaction stuff did not work. I have always ONE row in the table for each test which must work independently from each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> as the database is never touched

Surely it's touched. Everything that happens within the transaction happens in the database. Identity values and sequences (if any) are incremented, triggers fire, referential constraints are checked, etc. etc. The only thing is, it happens in isolation and in the end everything (except incremented identities and sequences) is reverted.

> Are there any downsides of using this approach?

Not really. I use this approach extensively in my own code and it has great merits. Green tests give a very high level of assurance. I will never feel safe with "real" unit test using mocked contexts and `DbSet`'s (although I use unit test for many other things).

But there are some restrictions you should be aware of.

- Identity / sequence values are not deterministic, so you can't assert them. As I said, these values will not be rolled back. If you really need asserts in this area, you can reset identities/sequences after each test.
- We can't ever test concurrency issues by this approach.
- You can't open a connection to another database, or even to the same database if its connection string differs in the slightest detail (e.g. a different application name, or different MARS setting), without DTC kicking in. In the application code this would be possible because there these different calls wouldn't be wrapped in a `TransactionScope`. So maybe not all application paths can easily be tested this way.
- Developers should use their own copy of the test database. If multiple developers (and maybe a build server) run tests on the same database they may deadlock one another.

Comment: Then I felt into the identity not reset trap. My tests worked each for itself but when I ran them together I got Concurrency errors due to wrong Id. I need to have each test a new starting Id else my multiple tests would have assumptions nobody can guess, that would be a bad dependency. So multiple user can`t commit there stuff AND run the tests safely without deadlock? But thats a typical scenario if you ask me. Concurrency plays no role in this application.

Comment: It's because of the TransactionScope's isolation level and tests running relatively long that deadlocks can occur. Normally that wouldn't happen so quickly. One more advantage of each dev having their own database is that they can experiment with new db content without troubling others. If you need identity values (which I don't recommend, use natural keys) you have to run DBCC CHECKIDENT (reseed) after each test.

Comment: Oh the natural keys vs surrogate keys discussion is as old as humanity ;-)

Comment: I updated my question with my final code I use now and it works fine.Thanks and have fun with 50 points ;-)

Comment: I thought I did , then something came inbetween ;-)

Comment: now you have the fun! sorry I forgot that the solution + bounty are not coupled together!

Comment: I discovered one DRAWBACK in using the auto inc RESEED which occured only of course... when I ran all my tests together in a random order which I can not determine anyway. I got DbUpdateException`s because I would have to reseed the id`s for ALL sql tables for each test. And this just to get the correct entity by id. Its not worth the effort/complexity so I just get now ONE entity from a table and assert on this one without id-assertion.

Comment: I have a stored procedure that reseeds all tables after each test to the highest ID value at that moment. Never had issues with it. But then, I don't depend on any ID value in my tests (or business logic), I always assert with natural keys. I only do the reseed to help me when I'm designing integration tests.